# Schwarz Lemma Forever

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $D = \{z \mid |z| < 1\}$. From all the analytic functions over $D$, which satisfy $$f(0)=1, \quad f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$$find the function whose $\sup_{z \in D}|f(z)|$ is the least possible. Prove that this function is unique, i.e. no other function gets such a low supremum.

All I can say is that ignoring all $f$'s whose supremum is infinite, if $M$ is the supremum of a certain function $f$, take $\frac{f}{M}$, and then by the (extended) schwarz lemma,

$$\left|\frac{f(z)}{M}\right| \leq \left|\frac{z-\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}z}\right| $$

How to continue?

Comment: Why "forever"...?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Such a simple lemma, generating a total of $\infty$ different questions

Comment: I love the title!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track with 
$$ \tag{*}
 \left|\frac{f(z)}{M}\right| \leq \left|\frac{z-\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}z}\right| \, .
$$
Setting $z = 0$, $f(0) = 1$ gives
$$
 \frac 1M \le \frac 12
$$
so that $M \ge 2$.

If $M = 2$ then equality holds in $(*)$ 
for $z = 0$, this implies
$$
 \frac{f(z)}2 = \lambda \frac{z-\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}z}
$$
for some constant $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ with $|\lambda | = 1$.
Setting $z = 0$ again shows that
$$
 f(z) = -2 \frac{z-\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}z}
$$
is the unique function for which the minimal supremum $M = 2$
is attained.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks Martin!